# How to define a beamer slide in a .sty file

Tags: beamer, auxiliary-files

I created a beamer slide use for transition or to thank audience. How may I put it in the .sty file of my theme ?

```
\begingroup
 \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=fore!115}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\begin{spacing}{2.0}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textcolor{white}{
\begin{Huge} A BIG TITLE \end{Huge}
}}
\end{center}
\end{spacing}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{A PICTURE} 
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\endgroup
```

I would like somethink like the sequence `\title{MY TITLE}`, `\setbeamertemplate{title page}` and `\maketitle` for a new type of slide. I think I have to define the new beamertemplate and call it in the main... but I do not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to simply define your thank-you-frame as a new command

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\myendpage}[1]{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
            \begin{center}
            \textbf{\textcolor{white}{
                    \begin{Huge} #1 \end{Huge}
                }}
            \end{center}
            \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-grid-100x100bp.pdf} 
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
}   


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}         

    \myendpage{my message}                      

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would also remove the navigation bar.

Comment: Yes good idea..., just a `[plain]` option to frame.