# Create equivalent to maketitle for beamer template

Tags: beamer, titles

I would like to predefine a closing slide containing the title of the presentation as well as the name of the author.

For this I would like to define some kind of equivalent to maketitle (e.g. makeendcard) in my beamer class file which creates the slide.

How can I do this?

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228424/how-to-define-a-beamer-slide-in-a-sty-file/228429#228429

Comment: and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375139/how-to-always-append-a-default-frame-at-the-end-of-a-beamer-presentation-using-a/375141#375141

Comment: Do the linked posts solve your problem?

Comment: You're welcome! Have fun with beamer :)